# Azure DevOps showing "failed" Status under commit history when build is partially succeeded (should show "warning" or similar)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

In my pipeline I have a task (among others) that either succeeds or succeeds with issues, controlled by:

```
if (-Not $packagesAreUpToDate) {Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=SucceededWithIssues;]"}
```

This task makes the entire job (containing other tasks) have the status "warning", which is desired.

[image: example]

The issue is when observing the commit history, where the pipeline appears as if they have failed (when they should have the status "Warning" or something similar).

[image: example]

Is there a way to fix this, or is it a bug or feature which has not yet been added by Azure DevOps?